# PHP PDO how to update information

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

I am very new to PHP, I am using PHP MVC with PDO.

I'm trying to update the first name and last name of my 'Profile' table for a given user ID.

Here's my **model**:

```
public function update(){
    $stmt = $this->_connection->prepare("UPDATE Profile SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Here's my **controller**:

```
        $prof = $this->model('Profile');
        $myProfile = $prof->getProfile($_SESSION['username']);

        if(isset($_POST['action'])){
                 $myProfile ->first_name = $_POST['First_name'];
                 $myProfile ->last_name = $_POST['Last_name'];
                 $myProfile ->update();

        }
```

It does not work, I'm getting the following **error**:

`PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (points to excute in model)`

Comment: The error message is quite clear, you use both positional parameter `?` and named parameter `:user_id`. You can't mix, use one type only.

Comment: Also, you have 3 parameters, but you bind only 1.

Comment: @catcon What should my update query look like? All the videos i watch don't have MVC.

Comment: @catcon I'm not quite sure what my update query should look like. If I put ? on user_id i get an error saying no bound [parameters

Comment: You have 3 parameters but you bind ONLY 1, here is how you use it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @catcon How would I bind first_name? I am doing the update() in the model. Would $_POST['First_name'] even work in the model

Answer (score 0):

**Your update() function should look like this:**

```
public function update() {

    $stmt = $this->_connection->prepare('UPDATE profile SET first_name = :first_name, last_name = :last_name WHERE user_id = :user_id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $_POST['First_name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last_name ', $_POST['Last_name']);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

**Also:**

- You have a typo in your SQL query (e.g. `,` before `WHERE`)
- Avoid mixing uppercase/lowercase in variable names
- Double-check your inputs (not empty, and matching the expected format) before updating the database